# How to check memory allocation for a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management

```
var test = [{a:1,b:2}];

test.value = test;
```

For the above code, I would like to see how much memory occupied by browser. Is there any side effects in performance (Since *test* variable is used recursively).
I have created an example function from [gist](https://gist.github.com/zensh/4975495) but getting Maximum stack calls exceeded. I am just curious to understand the problems of using iterative approach.

I know we can modify above code to make it non-recursive as below:

```
var test = [{a:1,b:2}];

test.value = [...test];
```

Comment: You'll need to show your code. The memory added in a self referential property should be tiny. Your memory error is likely that you're infinitely recursing because of that reference. That will be a problem in any environment.

Comment: Also, adding a property to an array like that is unusual, unless the property is numeric. Were you trying to push a new member into the array?

Comment: If i understand properly, i cannot check memory error since it's infinitely recursing. Adding a property to an array is unusual and i'll never follow this approach i just saw somewhere using array like this. So i am trying to understand problems of using this way @slappy

Answer (score 0):

JS always takes assignments from objects as memory references, there is a lot of ways to only copy the object's value.

This is my favorite one

```
test.value = Object.assign({}, test);
```

More generic

```
object_copy = Object.assign({}, object_origin)
```

What that code does is merge the original object's value into a new one that we initializate as a empty object `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Try chrome memory profile snapshot

I just wrote a small code to check the amount of memory allocation during your operation and recorded memory allocation using chrome devtool.

Here is the code that I've wrote:

```html
<HTML>
<body>
    <button onclick="startTest()">Start Test</button>
</body>
<script>
    function startTest() {
        var test = [{a:1,b:2}];
        test.value = test;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

When the button clicked the startTest() function runs.

So I started recording the memory allocation and pressed the `Start Test` button, and here is the result:
[image: Result]

The thin blue line in the picture shows that the memory allocated for the variable `test` and deallocated by the garbage collector very soon. this means that there is no recursion or any memory allocation problem.